# Time Calculation returning a NaN result

Tags: javascript

I am not very good at scripts, but I have created a PDF fillable form to calculate hours worked. When there is no data entered, the result fields show `NaN:NaN`, is there a way to hide this if the fields are blank?

The script formula I have used is.....

```
var hrsStart = parseInt(this.getField("hrsstart1").value.split(":")[0]);
var minStart = parseInt(this.getField("hrsstart1").value.split(":")[1]);
var hrsEnd = parseInt(this.getField("hrsend1").value.split(":")[0]); 
var minEnd = parseInt(this.getField("hrsend1").value.split(":")[1]);
if (minStart > minEnd) { 
  var minRez = 60 + minEnd - minStart;
  var hrsRez = hrsEnd - 1 - hrsStart; 
} else { 
  var minRez = minEnd - minStart;
  var hrsRez = hrsEnd - hrsStart; 
} 
this.getField("Totalhrs1").value = hrsRez + ":" + minRez;
```

When there is no data entered, the result fields show `NaN:NaN`, is there a way to hide this if the fields are blank?

Comment: It seems to working fine when there is data entered, I have 5 days to sheet and have tested with varied different start and end times and it works

Answer (score 1):

Use NaN checker function isNaN() like below:

```
if(!(isNaN(hrsRez)) && !(isNaN(minRez)) {
    this.getField("Totalhrs1").value = hrsRez + ":" + minRez;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var startValue = this.getField("hrsstart1").value;
var endValue = this.getField("hrsend1").value;

var timeValue = '';

if(startValue && endValue)
{
    var startArr = startValue.split(":");
    var endArr = endValue.split(":");

    var hrsStart = parseInt(startArr[0]);
    var minStart = parseInt(startArr[1]);
    var hrsEnd = parseInt(endArr[0]); 
    var minEnd = parseInt(endArr[1]);

    if(!isNaN(hrsStart) && !isNaN(minStart) && !isNaN(hrsEnd) && !isNaN(minEnd))
    {
        var minRez, hrsRez;
        if (minStart > minEnd) { 
          minRez = 60 + minEnd - minStart;
          hrsRez = hrsEnd - 1 - hrsStart; 
        } else { 
          minRez = minEnd - minStart;
          hrsRez = hrsEnd - hrsStart; 
        } 
        timeValue = hrsRez + ":" + minRez;
    }
}

this.getField("Totalhrs1").value = timeValue;
```

Comment: I have added a second part to the calculation to take off a lunch break, i just copied your script and changed it, but it doesn't work and also doesn't update if a change a value. the first part works great but no the second part, so it needs to use the Totalhrs1 - the lunchhrs1 can you help me. @Pinetree

Comment: I don't know how to help unless you paste your code here.

Comment: It won't let me add it here as it is too long sorry, but i used the script you gave me above and changed hrsstart1 to Totalhrs1 and hrsend1 to lunchbreak1 so it takes the total and deducts the lunchbreak. @Pinetree

Comment: You can edit your question to paste your second part code there to make people more clear about your problem, I don't know if I can help but someone may.